# How do you create a PDF from multiple images? Now with more grid problems

Tags: printing, pdf

So I have a ton of 825x1125 images ( (>300, in png format but I can make jpegs). I need to create a printable PDF with them (to print playing card prototypes). They have to be in a 3x3 grid pattern in the Letter format (they're meant for 300dpi).

I'm pretty sure I can batch resize them beforehand if it helps.

I'm guessing you can do this with convert or something but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you know a bit of LaTeX, I would use `pdflatex` for this --- it's quite easy to script.

The trick is generating a file with this header:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
```

and then for each line of photos

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{file01-01.png}\quad
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{file01-02.png}\quad
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{file01-03.png}\par
```

--- these are three images on a line, separated by a bit of space; and after three lines you put a

```
\clearpage
```

and at the end of the file a

```
\end{document}
```

You can generate the file with the language you want; save it in a file called `whatever.tex` and then process it with

```
 pdflatex whatever
```

With more LaTeX you can easily add captions, titles, frames or whatever you want. I understand it's a bit of steep curve to learn, but it's quite useful.

Comment: Alright I'll try this

Answer (score 2):

For simple converting of *.jpg's to one *.pdf I use `convert` from ImageMagick package:
`convert *.jpg out.pdf`.

For your task you can use `-mosaic` option (see [official docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#mosaic)) or `montage` command (see [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/)).