# A simple picture editing software - for adding text to image

Tags: photo-management, editing

I'm looking for a software to combine photo and text, I don't need special effects just that one function. Is there a free software that is also easy to use?

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I was hoping to find something that could outline the text in a high contrast white-text black-border way (like image macros/memes do), I didn't find anything handy, its super easy to do in the cairo library/toolkit, I just gave up and I'll manually text-to-path, and stroke-path on a different layer in gimp when I have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following softwares meet your request.

GUI software:

- single file: GIMP
- bulk files: phatch

CLI software:

- ImageMagick

Answer (score 2):

#### Command line

Very fast, medium difficulty:
[Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
For some ideas on how to use the convert -annotate flag of Imagemagick, check the answers to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620423/merging-multiple-images-into-one-document-and-add-any-caption-label-to-them/620429#620429) question:

#### GUI

The ever classic, generally steep learning curve, but very easy for the simple task you asked for:
[The Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)

In Gimp, you will find the functionality under tools --> text

Another alternative, I have never tested myself though is [pinta](http://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/).

Answer (score 2):

While i would recommend [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) as well there are for sure alternatives.
If it comes to being small and limited you could take a look on [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/).

**Shutter** itself is a screenshot tool in the first place, 
but it has an edit mode with some limited editing.

It can as well load images and therefor isn't limited to screenshots/images generated with shutter itself.

The sidebar in the edit-mode comes with a *Add text* dialog which should cover your needs.

#### Install options

Shutter should be available in the default repositories, but the project itself recommends using a ppa to get the latest versions.

In case you are using the default repositories, you can install shutter via:

```
sudo apt install shutter
```

Instructions regarding the ppa can be found [here](http://shutter-project.org/downloads/).